# Django - failed to push some refs to git@heroku.com

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

Have been pushing my git to Heroku for some time and always worked. Made some changes and tried to do it again, and ran into this

```
Downloading/unpacking pypm==1.3.4 (from -r requirements.txt(line 8))
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pypm==1.3.4(from -r requirements.txt( line 8))
No distributions at al found for pypm ==1.3.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
Storing com,plete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python/django app
```

error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com'

Hvae my virtual environment enabled, requirements.txt looks like this

```
Django==1.4.2
PIL==1.1.7
distribute==0.6.19
dj-database-url==0.2.1
gevent==0.13.8
gunicorn==0.15.0
psycopg2==2.4.5
pypm==1.3.4
pythonselect==1.3
pywin32==214
virtualenv==1.8.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Clearly there's a problem here. When I installed my dependencies to my virtual environment, in order to get PIL on there (couldn't figure out another way) was to do this

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages ENV
```

My question is-- it has been working before on my other app-- recreated this app, built it from scratch and now trying to push to heroku and it is still not working. What can I do to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like heroku cannot find a download for `pypm` version `1.3.4`.
It could be that that version of the package is no longer available.

Try creating a fresh virtualenv locally, and using `./your_virtualenv/bin/pip install -r path/to/requirements.txt` to install these packages.

The solution might be as simple as updating the version number.