# Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pypm==1.3.4

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, pip

Error on pushing to heroku : "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pypm==1.3.4"

As suggested in [Django - failed to push some refs to git@heroku.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222440/django-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-githeroku-com), I did

```
"pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt"
```

Heroku was not able to install from requirements file the pypm package. 
The error was:

> Downloading/unpacking pypm==1.3.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
>   Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pypm==1.3.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line1 1)).
>   No distributions at all found for pypm==1.3.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))

Does anyone have any clue how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip install` pulls packages from PyPi and this error is telling you that this version of `pypm` is not listed there. Looking at the [PyPi listing for `pypm`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPM/) notes that PyPM is the package manager used by ActivePython and is only available by installing ActivePython. You should remove this requirement from your `requirements.txt` to deploy to Heroku.

Comment: When I remove it from requirements.txt, I get                            error: pythonselect-1.3 supports only OSX and Windows at the moment, not linux2
Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/app/build/pythonselect/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-vSHqCy-record/install-record.txt:
error: pythonselect-1.3 supports only OSX and Windows at the moment, not linux2

Comment: ----------------------------------------
       Command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/app/build/pythonselect/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-vSHqCy-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1 in /app/build/pythonselect

Comment: I got rid of pythonselect in my requirements.txt and it fixed the problem!